# How can I install Outlook (PWA) for all users on a machine and set it to default for mailto?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, chromium, file-association, mailto, progressive-web-app

I'm attempting to install Outlook (PWA) at the computer level or via group policy or via registry edit. I need users to be able to click mailto links and have Outlook (PWA) pop up for them to either sign into or use.

Installing Outlook (PWA) manually and setting Outlook (PWA) as the default mailto app works if done manually but I need this automated for all users.

Background is that the user profiles are temporary and I need this set at either the machine level or upon first login. I can't use the full version of Outlook for this. I would be willing to use office365 version if possible.

Below is what I have so far. It kind of works. When clicking a mailto link, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even prompt for which app to use.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge String Name = WebAppInstallForceList Value = [{"fallback_app_name": "Outlook (PWA)","default_launch_container": "window","url": "https://outlook.office.com"}]
```

It installs an app with the name of Outlook (PWA) and the correct URL. However though, if you directly navigate to Outlook, it still prompts you to install Outlook (PWA). Also, it gives you the option to open the Outlook (PWA) app that was force installed.

I also have the protocol handler registered for Outlook to handle mailto links.

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\Recommended String Name = RegisteredProtocolHandlers Value = [{"url": "https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?mailtouri=%s","default": true,"protocol": "mailto"}]
```

I'm missing a method of getting this force installed PWA app to be the default app for mailto.

ProgID for this Outlook PWA app is inconsistent so I can't use an xml for default file association. I'd prefer the xml method, if someone can think of a way to make it work.

Any assistance in trying to find a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like manually installing Outlook as a PWA from within Edge registers the PWA as a protocol handler for "mailto" in Windows; however, using the GPO/Registry to install does not. There are several other differences to the way it is installed if you do it manually vs GPO/Registry as well. Here is the solution I got to work for me.

**1. Configure Outlook PWA Installation and register protocol handler in Edge**

Here is the registry. You can also configure this with GPO if you download the MSEdge templates.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"WebAppInstallForceList"="[{\"custom_name\": \"Outlook\", \"install_as_shortcut\": true, \"create_desktop_shortcut\": true, \"default_launch_container\": \"window\", \"url\": \"https://outlook.office.com/mail\",\"custom_icon\": {\"hash\": \"E35D94B76894D6ECA96FF5B1A12D94DFE73485EF3C52CB5B4395BE8FFAC1CB45\", \"url\": \"https://outlook.office.com/mail/favicon.ico\"}}]"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\Recommended]
"RegisteredProtocolHandlers"="[{\"url\": \"https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?mailtouri=%s\",\"default\": true,\"protocol\": \"mailto\"}]"
```

**2. Add the Outlook PWA as a protocol handler for "mailto" in Windows.**

Download an Outlook .ico file and save it as C:\ProgramData\OutlookPWA\Outlook.ico. This file is referenced in the registry entries below as the icon for when you select the Outlook PWA as the default app in Settings.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA]
@="OutlookPWA"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\Application]
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\ProgramData\\OutlookPWA\\Outlook.ico,0"
"ApplicationName"="OutlookPWA"
"ApplicationDescription"="Outlook Progressive Web Application"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\ProgramData\\OutlookPWA\\Outlook.ico,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge_proxy.exe\" --profile-directory=Default --app=https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?mailtouri=%1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\shell\runas]
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OutlookPWA\shell\runas\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge_proxy.exe\" --profile-directory=Default --do-not-de-elevate --app=https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?mailtouri=%1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"OutlookPWA"="Software\\Clients\\Mail\\OutlookPWA\\Capabilities"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA]
@="OutlookPWA"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\Capabilities]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"mailto"="OutlookPWA"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\ProgramData\\OutlookPWA\\Outlook.ico,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\OutlookPWA\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge_proxy.exe\" --profile-directory=Default --app=https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?mailtouri=%1"
```

**3. Set the default app association.**

Create an XML file that contains the default for mailto (Set to OutlookPWA). Feel free to add any other defaults you want to this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
  <Association Identifier="mailto" ProgId="OutlookPWA" ApplicationName="OutlookPWA" />
</DefaultAssociations>
```

Import default app associations from that XML file either by GPO *(Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer > Set a default associations configuration file)* or with DISM. Dism will only apply to new users. It will not set defaults for existing users. If you need to set the default for existing users on the PC you will need to use the GPO.

Dism - Apply to Image

```
Dism /Image:YourImage /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:YourXMLFile
```

Dism - Apply to already imaged computer

```
Dism /Online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:YourXMLFile
```

**That's it!**

Bonus: If you actually use Edge and you don't want it to pop up asking if you want to allow this website to open a program when you click a `mailto` link, use either of the following:

Machine

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\mailto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

User

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\mailto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify Outlook.com as the default mail handler by following the guidance here: https://www.techradar.com/news/outlookcom-can-now-be-your-default-email-client

Comment: Unfortunately the given example is the manual method that wouldn't work for all users. I'm not sure if there's a known solution for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get a valid answer to your question, or were you able to figure this out?

I noticed Faery's response which doesn't help.

I have the issue I'm facing, just curious if you were able to get it working or not.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).